# working with 3 columns of data in ggplot2: x, y1, and y2 into a stacked bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 3 column data. The first column, depth, should be on the x axis. The other two columns are nr and r. I need to plot the data in a stacked barplot with A on the bottom and B on the top of nr. The data is very large (ie. the read depth goes from 0 to 1022), so I can't type everything out specifically in r or on here. Here's an example of what the data would look like:

```
Depth       r        nr
6          2395     2904
8          0        3095
9          2689     0
12         3894     3578
15         5        4739
```

the r and the nr have to be on the y axis, and the depth has to be on the x axis. I've tried everything I can think of and am unable to get a 'height' to use or to just get the basic equation.

Answer (score 2):

Work in long format

```
#using reshape2::melt
library(reshape2)

 # assuming your original data.frame is called `D`
 longD <- melt(D, id.var = 1)

 ggplot(longD, aes(x = Depth, y = value, colour = variable, fill = variable)) +
   geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `barchart` from `lattice` you can deal with wide format :

```
library(lattice)
barchart(r+nr~factor(Depth),data=dt,stack=TRUE,auto.key=TRUE)
```

[image]

equivalent to this , using long format from @mnel answer:

```
barchart(value~factor(Depth),data=longD,
                  groups=variable,stack=TRUE,auto.key=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to show base R graphics can match it as well, and assuming your data.frame is called `dat`:

```
barplot(
  t(dat)[2:3,],
  names.arg=t(dat)[1,],
  space=c(0,diff(t(dat)[1,])),
  axis.lty=1
)
```

[image]